# Deleting Internal Files

Tags: android

My app downloads two relatively small files from a server and stores them in internal storage. We have recently run into a situation where we will go to an activity with a full screen map. We found that if we background the app, return, and then force kill the app, the files are getting deleted by the OS.

We can check their existence in the activity and we see they are still around during onPause and onStop. The function onDestroy shows they no longer exists. We have no clue why these files are being deleted.

Note: These files are downloaded and accessed at startup. They are not being accessed when we go into the Maps activity. Furthermore, it does not occur on if we repeat these steps in other activities.

Any thoughts or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You store the downloaded files within the path returned from `getFilesDir()`?